# How to get a column to display percentages in R

Tags: r

I have produced a table which shows the number of different people in each income group form a data table, I would like to produce a column which shows this as a percentage.

This is my current code that produces a table with a column with the number of people in each income group

```
ind_and_countries %>%
  group_by(Income_Group)%>%
  summarise(Number = n())%>%
  arrange(desc(Number))
```

I have tried using
mutate(Percentage = Number/colSums(Number)*100)
I think the issue is when I need to divide by the total number and can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: you can also use `proportions(Number)`

Answer (score 0):

The formattable package used here is only affecting the appearance. You could use Number/sum(Number) alone.

```
ind_and_countries %>%
  group_by(Income_Group)%>%
  summarise(Number = n())%>%
  mutate(Percentage = formattable::percent(Number / sum(Number))) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Number))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `mutate(Percentage = Number / sum(Number) * 100)`

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to get R to plot this in a graph form but gg-plot doesn't seem to want to plot it

Comment: Ask another question, provide a small sample of your data and explain your desired output, then we can help you.

Comment: ggplot(IncomeGroup_count, aes(x=Income_Group, y= Percentage, colour = 'lightblue'))